# How to solve this embedded question

Tags: grammar

What is wrong with you? how to change this into embedded question can someone helps me, please?

Answer (score 1):

An "embedded question" is simply a label for a declarative statement that contains a clause expressing an unknown:

> The doctors don't know *what is wrong with you*.

The subordinate clause *what is wrong with you* is an interrogative clause.